# SSRS Switch Case - how to sort by 2 field values

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, field

`=Switch(Fields!RptSeq.Value="1",Fields!PatientId.Value,
        Fields!RptSeq.Value="2",Fields!RxNumber.Value,Fields!PatientId.Value
        Fields!RptSeq.Value="5",Fields!DoctorName.Value,Fields!PatientId.Value,
        1=1,Fields!PatientId.Value)`

I need to sort my report thrugh expression like this, if the sort seq is 1 then by patient ID, if 2 then the report should be first sorted by RxNumber then by PatientID. I don't know how to sort for 2 field values.

if I do Fields!RxNumber.Value,Fields!PatientId.Value the sort does not work, if I do Fields!RxNumber.Value+Fields!PatientId.Value I'm getting error wrong sort expression.

appreciate your help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can add two lines in the sorting tab of the tablix; one for the first sort priority with this expression:

```
=Switch(Fields!RptSeq.Value="1",Fields!PatientId.Value,
        Fields!RptSeq.Value="2",Fields!RxNumber.Value,
        Fields!RptSeq.Value="5",Fields!DoctorName.Value,
        1=1,Fields!PatientId.Value)
```

and the other for the second sort priority set the field to :

```
Fields!PatientId.Value
```

Comment: on the sorting expression of the same group?

Comment: yes, if you right-click on tablix properties, then Sorting, you can add as many columns as you need; in this case you need 2; then you can add the expressions above respectively in the first and second column added

Comment: actually I just realised that the second priority is a tautology; it will always be  Fields!PatientId.Value, so no need to do expression on the second line, just set the field to Fields!PatientId.Value. Answer edited.

Comment: Well pointed, strings solution is not an option if multiples lengths are present (which is most possible).

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it by passing the parameter to the Dataset query also.

Sample:

```
declare @RptSeq int = 1

select * from Table
order by 
        (case @RptSeq when 1 then PatientId
                      when 2 then RxNumber
                      when 5 then DoctorName
                      else PatientId
         end),
        (case @RptSeq when 2 then PatientId
                      when 5 then PatientId
         end)
```